# Git commit from inside script fails

Tags: git, bash

I wrote the following bash function which should create a commit with my username hardcoded. Yes I know about `git config`, this is just a minimal example to demonstrate the problem I'm having.

```
# lib.sh
function lock-commit() {
    local commit_author="Varun Madiath <varun@example.com>"
    git commit --author="${commit_author}" "$@"
}
```

However when I run this, it gives me the error below. Running the command on the command line directly does not result in the error.

```
[vmadiath@magma ac-test]$ source lib.sh
[vmadiath@magma ac-test]$ lock-commit -m "test"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <vmadiath@localhost.localdomain>) not allowed
```

Given that I'm explicitly passing the author, I shouldn't need to set the `user.email` and `user.name` config settings.

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can correct this behaviour.

Comment: It works for me. Try cutting your script down to just calling `lock-function` or showing your whole script or at least how you're calling `lock-function`.

Comment: Also, what version of Git are you using? I believe `--author` hasn't always been there.

Comment: I'm using git version 2.6.2. I've updated the example without my wrapper scrpit so that I'm calling the function directly.

Comment: Nope, still can't replicate it with 2.6.2. Are you sure `git` is `git` and not some wrapper? Also check there's no `git-commit` in your PATH. Finally, maybe post your `~/.gitconfig` and `.git/config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git records two details for each commit: the **author** (which is what you're overriding) and the **committer** (which is what it's looking for in your settings).

This allows one user to commit changes on behalf of another, while recording details of both users in the repository.

Comment: Thanks, this had me figure it out.
Turns out lib.sh also overrode the `HOME` variable, which was causing git to not find my settings.